VS Code running debug and listening but never accepts the connection
I have been using VSCode for a long time on my computer at work and it runs fine using PHP/Xdebug. It's Windows 10. Currently everything works.
I just recently got a new computer running Windows 11. I set everything up exactly the same way. My settings in VSCode are synced, same extensions, same everything.

Running out of a Docker container.
Xdebug wizard says everything is installed fine.
I have disabled my firewall
netstat -aon shows the port 8000 listening.

Whether I try to hit localhost:8000 with Postman/Telnet my debugger sits here and never accepts the connection. Maybe it's something with Windows 11? Anyone have any ideas?

launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug on Docker",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-S",
                "localhost:8000",
                "-t",
                "."
            ],
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}





Show your Xdebug settings from php.ini. Best way -- call xdebug_info() and provide it's output -- it will show the actual live settings. Right now it sounds like Xdebug is not trying to connect to VSCode (i.e. you are expecting it to happen automatically but it needs a trigger (a cookie or a param) to do that). 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it will show there.


@LazyOne Beautiful! finally a log I can look at. so I got [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). From what I could see host.docker.internal had the wrong ip and made it my machines ip and that still doesnt work.
